# Session-Cookie not sent in CORS environment

Tags: angular, express, cookies, cross-domain, session-cookies

I'm desperately trying to get session cookies to work in my environment, but without luck so far.

My backend is a node/express application, running at port 3000. CORS is enabled like this:

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:4300",
    allowedHeaders: [ "Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization", "x-xsrf-token" ],
    credentials: true
};
if (isDebug) {
    corsOptions.maxAge = 1;
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I'm using express-session and passport for login. The session is configured like this:

```
const options = {
    secret: '...',
    cookie: { httpOnly: true }
};

app.use(session(options));
```

The frontend is an Angular 2 SPA, running at port 4300. When I'm serving the frontend from my express server, everything works as expected. But when not, I'm experiencing the following obscure problem:

The login route returns a cookie with the session ID. But the next request to the backend is sent with a *different* session ID?! I have no idea, where this different session ID could come from. Especially since the session cookie is marked as HTTP-only.

The HTTP-requests are sent as follows:

```
const response = this.http.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
```

I tried the following:

- Made sure that third party cookies are allowed in the browser => it was fine.
- Tried to set httpOnly to false => no luck.
- Experimented with cookie domain: set it to the address of the backend - no luck. Then to the address of the frontend - didn't work either.
- Cleared browser and cookie caches, tried out Google Chrome and Edge. Nothing helped.

Does anybody have an idea which part of the puzzle is missing?

Thanks a lot,
Steven

Answer (score 3):

Omg, I narrowed it down and finally found out the problem:

The login-request did *not* have the withCredentials-Flag set...I thought that this would only be needed for the subsequent requests, after the cookies have already been received. But actually it is there to store the cookies that are received cross-domain.